# Compressing and resaving multipage Tiff images

Tags: c#, compression, tiff

I am trying to open up an already existing multi-page tiff image, break it up into all of its separate pages and save those to an array of bitmaps, compress the pages and resave them back into a TIFF image that is smaller than when we started.

My restriction is that this has to be able to run on Windows Server 2003, meaning I have to use `wpfImage` to compress the image.

So far I have been able to grab all of the pages and I am able to successfully save a single-page tiff, but my code fails if I try to resave a multi-page TIFF. Here is the main compression code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {

                            TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
                            ms.Position = 0;
                            for (int i = 1; i < bmp.Length; i ++ )
                            {
                                //ms.SetLength(0);
                                Bitmap page = new Bitmap(bmp[i]);
                                page.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);


                                BitmapImage wpfImage = new BitmapImage();
                                wpfImage.BeginInit();
                                wpfImage.StreamSource = ms;
                                wpfImage.EndInit();

                                encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4;
                                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wpfImage));
                                encoder.Save(ms);
                            }                               
                            Image tiff = Image.FromStream(ms);
                            tiff.Save(location);

                        }
```

As I said, this code works with single-page TIFFs and I get a pretty good amount of compression. I am just lost as to how to apply this to multi-page tiffs. The main error I get is that I am not able to call the `Save()` method more than once on an encoder, but how am I supposed to grab all pages after the first one if that is the case?

Comment: Can you set all of the Frames first, then call encoder.Save at the end?

Comment: You have to add the pages as frames to the first tiff image. Look for it on your favourite search engine (".net create multipage tiff").